# WSO2 Scim Password reset

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Are there any wso2 scim apis that help in password resets? I have tried using the normal user update but it does not seem to work and there was no mention of an api specific to password reset. I am using a node app to access wso2. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the password using a SCIM PUT or a PATCH request for the particular user.

Ex. for SCIM PATCH request

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin -X PATCH -d '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Doe","givenName":"John"},"userName":"john", "password":"test123", "emails":[{"value":"john@acme.com","type":"work"},{"value":"john@home.com","type":"home"}]}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/3bb710ba-32c8-4469-82ae-67ecd11e58f9
```